# call JFrame from active running or background JFrame without calling new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am having problem with JFrames.

Currently I have 2 JFrames running, 
MainFrame with a button to call Frame2. 
And from Frame2 with JButton, I wan to call the current running/background MainFrame without calling another new MainFrame.

Actually I am making a search function on Frame2 and when click button search, wanna display the results in the Main Frame.

Answer (score 0):

If Frame2 inherits MainFrame then do this:

```
Frame2.getParent().getBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of solutions for such problems. It really depends on what best suits your use case.

In the example below I use an interface to issue callbacks to `MainFrame` from `Frame2`. I assume the latter is a member of `MainFrame`. This sort of solution makes it easy for you to use the same `Frame2` implementation in multiple implementations of `MainFrame` (a common search for more than one frame).

Note that code below is just skeleton code to demonstrate the pattern being used.

```java
public class Frame2 extends JFrame {

    private final Controller controller;
    private JButton button;

    public Frame2(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        button = new JButton("Search");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // do search and create result object
                Object results = new Object();
                Frame2.this.controller.displaySearchResults(results);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Controller {
        // users implement this
        public void displaySearchResults(Object results);
    }
}
```

```java
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private Frame2 search;
    private JButton button;

    public MainFrame() {
        search = new Frame2(new ControllerImplementation());
        button = new JButton("Show search");
        button.addActionListener(new ShowSearch());
    }

    private class ShowSearch implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            search.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    private class ControllerImplementation implements Frame2.Controller {
        public void displaySearchResults(Object results) {
            // display results by accessing members of MainFrame
        }

    }
}
```

This may help you achieve what you want.

Comment: @Boon DerMaster glad to hear that. If this answer aswered your question you should mark it as answered.